# Tough Wordpress Conditional if_page NOT display widget

Tags: php, wordpress

I've tried many variations and can't seem to get the syntax right.  In one of my Wordpress theme pages I have the following Widget code.  I want to append the existing functionality to where it removes this widget if the page name is 'event-view' or page id is '640'...how do I do this?

```
<?php
    // A third sidebar for widgets
    if ( is_active_sidebar( 'third-widget-area' ) ) : ?>

        <div id="third" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
            <ul class="xoxo">
                <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'third-widget-area' ); ?>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- #secondary .widget-area -->
```

Comment: Don't forget http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ for future queries :)

Comment: Cool!  Did not realize there was a SE for wordpress, will do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
// A third sidebar for widgets
if ( is_active_sidebar('third-widget-area') && !is_page(640) ) : ?>

    <div id="third" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
        <ul class="xoxo">
            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'third-widget-area' ); ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

You can also check page by it's name `is_page('event-view')`

Answer (score 1):

try changing

```
if ( is_active_sidebar( 'third-widget-area' ) )
```

to

```
if ( is_active_sidebar( 'third-widget-area' ) && !is_page(640) )
```

this way you can check if the current page is any other than the one with the id 640; see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page

Answer (score 1):

Try out this.
You can give pass page_id in is_page() function.

```
if(is_page('640') || is_page('49'))
```

And for more details see below.
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/display-widget-on-certain-pages